# hover on span is not working

Tags: html, css

i am new to css, i have written code to display some text on hover. But it is not working

**HTML:**

```
<div id="onHover"> 5
<span>
    <ul>
        <li>Ankur</li>
        <li>Dhanuka</li>
    </ul>
</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#onHover span:hover
{
 bottom:130px;
 left:105px;
 padding:8px 8px 10px 8px;
 display:block;
 border:1px dashed #09f;
 background-color:#FFF;
 min-width:170px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:101;
}
#onHover span:hover ul {
font-weight:normal;
list-style:none;
margin:10px 0 0 0;
padding:0;
position:relative;
}
span {
display:none;
}
```

you can also see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ankurdhanuka/ccFxu/

please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `span:hover` can never be triggered because the span is hidden.

Comment: Spans can't contain uls.

Comment: @Juhana at the time of page load span will be hidden, on hover it should display span

Comment: `#onHover span:hover` – how do you expect this (the user hovering over the span) to happen, when you hid the span via `display:none`? Can hardly hover what’s not even there in the first place, hm?

Comment: span is in `display: none;` see modified css in http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/ccFxu/1/

Comment: @j08691 (offtopic), in HTML5 it's allowed to have a block-element inside an inline-element.

Comment: please give reason for down voting the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice Try, friend. Give  `:hover` to  `#onHover` as 5 is enclosed within `#onHover`.
Use position only if it is required.
check this. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ccFxu/3/

Comment: it is working, but on hover design is moving. where should i give z-index to it?

Comment: exactly i want to display the hover block in front rather than in that page

Comment: if it is needed http://jsfiddle.net/ccFxu/5/ will show the result. removing the `position:relative;` will show your result. or a slider will appear there. :)

Comment: see this http://rockhost.com/custom-web-design.php and hover on @299..i want something like this...

Comment: see on hover design is not getting disturbed. while in my coding, on hover design is getting disturbed

Answer (score 6):

Your HTML should look like this (the span is useless, so I took it out, it also isn't allowed in HTML4. It is in HTML5 tho...):

```
<div id="onHover"> 5
         <ul>
            <li>Ankur</li>
            <li>Dhanuka</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can add a :hover effect on the div, like this:

```
#onHover ul {
    display: none;
}
#onHover:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

As you can see, the :hover is on `#onHover`, but it triggers the `ul` within it.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/ccFxu/2/)

Comment: fiddle is working perfectly, but it is not working in my code..:(

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Add the rest of you CSS rule for rule, then you'll see where it goes wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `display:none` to the `span` through css.

The elements which are set as `display:none` will not be visible and are actually take no space in the view. Hence you cant able to hover on `span` which is actually not available because of `display:none`.